# Spaceship objects

Tags: python, object, static-methods

I'm trying to make a program which creates a spaceship and I'm using the status() method to display the ship's name and fuel values. However, it doesn't seem to be working. I think I may have messed something up with the status() method. I'm also trying to make it so that I can change the fuel values, but I don't want to create a new method to do so. I think I've taken a horrible wrong turn somewhere in there. Help please!

```
class Ship(object):

    def __init__(self, name="Enterprise", fuel=0):
        self.name=name
        self.fuel=fuel
        print "The spaceship", name, "has arrived!"

    def status():
        print "Name: ", self.name
        print "Fuel level: ", self.fuel
    status=staticmethod(status)

def main():

    ship1=Ship(raw_input("What would you like to name this ship?"))
    fuel_level=raw_input("How much fuel does this ship have?")
    if fuel_level<0:
        self.fuel=0
    else:
        self.fuel(fuel_level)

    ship2=Ship(raw_input("What would you like to name this ship?"))
    fuel_level2=raw_input("How much fuel does this ship have?")
    if fuel_level2<0:
        self.fuel=0
    else:
        self.fuel(fuel_level2)

    ship3=Ship(raw_input("What would you like to name this ship?"))
    fuel_level3=raw_input("How much fuel does this ship have?")
    if fuel_level3<0:
        self.fuel=0
    else:
        self.fuel(fuel_level3)

    Ship.status()

main()

raw_input("Press enter to exit.")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each ship has its own fuel, so static isn't the way to go.  If you don't want the parameter to look like a method, consider a property.  It encapsulates the value-checking of the fuel as well.

```
class Ship(object):

    def __init__(self, name="Enterprise", fuel=0):
        self.name = name
        self._fuel = fuel
        print "The spaceship", name, "has arrived!"

    def status(self):
        print "Name: ", self.name
        print "Fuel level: ", self.fuel

    @property
    def fuel(self):
        return self._fuel

    @fuel.setter
    def fuel(self,level):
        if level < 0:
            self._fuel = 0
        else:
            self._fuel = level
```

In main(), consider loops to initialize the ships and display status instead of repeating code, and use ship.fuel instead of self.fuel.  self is only valid in methods of the class.

```
def main():

    ships = []
    for n in range(4):
        ship = Ship(raw_input("What would you like to name this ship?"))
        ship.fuel = int(raw_input("How much fuel does this ship have?"))
        ships.append(ship)

    for ship in ships:
        ship.status()

main()
raw_input("Press enter to exit.")
```

Answer (score 4):

In your `status` method `self` is not defined, because you made it a static method. It makes more sense to make it non-static, since every ship has its individual name. So just say

```
def status(self):
    print "Name: ", self.name
    print "Fuel level: ", self.fuel
```

and later call

```
ship1.status()
ship2.status()
ship3.status()
```

Comment: +1.  Also, Jam, make sure your indentation is correct.  Both `__init__` and `status` must be indented in your class definition.

Comment: Yes. I'd be interested to know why the OP thought it should be a static method.

Comment: They are indented, it just didn't do it when I copied it here. Oh well. Haha, I'm not sure why I decided it should be static. I'm working through the Python book, and static methods were just covered, so I was attempting to make that work. But I suppose I should use it only when it makes sense!